# How to implement a check for whether a user inputted string, for a transcendental function, exists in the math module?

Tags: python, python-3.x

This is my first post, and I am a newcomer to coding (with Python 3 being my first language) so please be patient :)

**I have no idea** (or even what function to search for to try and learn myself) how to write some code that can use a while loop to check that a user typed transcendental function is a valid one, that exists in the math module:

```
 user_fn_str = str(input("Type a transcendental function in this form: e.g. 'sin' or 'exp'"))
```

and say the user typed:

```
sim
```

the check would fail (math.sim does not exist) and they'd remain in the while loop until there is a valid input.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can inspect the `dir(..)` of `math` like:

```
import math

name in dir(math)
```

But this will also give you `True` for things like `'__doc__'` and `'pi'`, so you have **no guarantee that it is a function**.

So what you have to do is fetch the attribute and inspect if it is *callable* by checking if it has a `__call__'` attribute attached to it. The full test would thus be something like:

```
import math

def is_math_function(funcname):
    func = getattr(math,funcname,None)
    return func is not None and hasattr(func, '__call__')
```

You can optimize this further because `None` has no `__call__`, so you can simply state:

```
def is_math_function(funcname):
    return hasattr(getattr(math,funcname,None),'__call__')
```

to make it a one-liner.

Some additional notes:

- If the test succeeds, that does **not** mean per se that it is a mathematical function: `math` could have included some additional functions like `isnan` for instance (ok, you can debate whether that is a mathematical function); and
- it says nothing about the **number of arguments**, it can be one (for `math.sin` for instance), but there could be multiple (or strictly speaking even no arguments, but perhaps that will not be the case for `math`).

Comment: Nice and complete answer !

Comment: @tagc: the user said "*that a user typed transcendental function is a valid one*". I interpreted this as: "the user enters a function he/she knows is transcendental. The question is however: is it supported in `math`?".

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem That makes sense.

Comment: @tagc Such an attribute does not exist anyhow in the `math` module so you cannot look for it.

Comment: @Ev.Kounis No, but my thinking is that there might be some other library (SymPy maybe?) that could tell you if a particular function is transcendental or not based on its name, which you'd add as an additional condition with what Willem's already done. But it's a long shot and if it's not something OP requires then it doesn't matter anyway.

Comment: @Tagc: well some math libraries could for instance attach a `__doc__` or some other data to the functions containing flags like `associative`, `commutative`, `transcendental`,... But afaik the `math` library does not support that. Evidently you can define these yourself.

Comment: @Tagc: furhermore automatic derivation is probably not possible because (a) of *Rice's theorem*; (b) because of floating point precision; but more because of (c) all functions implemented by a computer are non-transcendent: indeed either the interpolation is cut of after a number of sums, or the computer/processor uses a *lookup table*. So `sin` on a machine is not transcendental.

Comment: For style only, `isinstance(f, collections.abc.Callable)` might be nicer.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem Yeah, I was thinking of the lookup table possibility (just in case there actually is a library that provides some sort of `get_math_function_attributes(func_name)` function, as unlikely as that is).

Answer (score 3):

You may use `hasattr` built-in function.

```
import math
s1 = 'sim'
assert not hasattr(math, s1)
s2 = 'sin'
assert hasattr(math, s2)
```